# Xamarin bind a dynamic list of images to a grid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

first of all sorry for the mess, I'm kicking my head in this for a while already, I'm kind new in xamarin and starting with difficult problems. I'm trying to add dynamically a list of random images in a grid.

currently i have the grid printing like 
Name1      Detail1
filename1 filename2 filename3
Name2      Detail2
Filename1 filename2

```
var cell = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var grid = new Grid() { Padding = 8, RowSpacing = 5, ColumnSpacing = 5 };
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star) });
  Subtitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Images");
  grid.Children.Add(labelName, 0, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(labelDetail, 1, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(Subtitle, 1, 1);
```

the cell in the end is attached to a listview

```
 listdata.ItemTemplate = cell;
```

in the Object I have defined images as a string, I already tried to create another bind to a list, and create a listview of a custom call and add it to the grid, but throws an error and I can't see any description, it's something like sigsegv-without-stack trace
Also tried to instead of a grid, create a stack layout. again nothing.

CustomCell

```
           public class CustomNocCell : ViewCell
{

    public CustomCell()
    {
        //instantiate each of our views
        var image = new Image();
        var nameLabel = new Label();
        var typeLabel = new Label();
        var verticaLayout = new StackLayout();
        var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent };

        //set bindings
        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));

        //Set properties for desired design
        horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        horizontalLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
        nameLabel.FontSize = 24;

        //add views to the view hierarchy
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(verticaLayout);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(image);

        // add to parent view
        View = horizontalLayout;
    }
}
```

what I tried already that gave the error

```
   //ListView listView = new ListView();

        //listView.RowHeight = 60;
        //listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomNocCell));
        ////listView.ItemsSource = "ImagesNoc";
        //listView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "ImagesList");
```

ImagesList class

```
   [Ignore]
        public ListView ImagesList
        {
            get
            {


                ListView listView = new ListView();
                listView.RowHeight = 60;

                listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomNocCell));



                List<string> list = new List<string>();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Detail))
                {
                    foreach (string str in Detail.Split(';'))
                    {
                        list.Add(str);
                    }
                }



                listView.ItemsSource = list.Select(s => new { Name = s, Image = s.ToLower() + ".png" }).ToList();

                return listView;
            }

        }
```

I had the class also returning a simple List of type Name and Image that the CustomCell is waiting and nothing.

**EDIT**

```
 public class TestObject
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string countries { get; set; }

        }



        void load()
        {
            List<TestObject> list = new List<TestObject>();
            list.Add(new TestObject { title = "test1", countries = "esp,ita,prt" });
            list.Add(new TestObject { title = "test2", countries = "esp,ita" });
            list.Add(new TestObject { title = "test3", countries = "rus" });

            var labelTitle = new Label()
            {

                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            };
            listdata = new ListView();
            listdata.ItemsSource = list;

           var cell = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var grid = new Grid() { Padding = 8, RowSpacing = 5, ColumnSpacing = 5 };
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                labelTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "title");

                countriesLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "countries"); //here i want to make a customcell to show the images, like be able to "bind" and calc the countries split the string by "," and add (name + ".png") then show the image.
```

// i was able to do it in a listview when i have the source in my side.. in this one i have to bind and then calc..

```
                grid.Children.Add(labelTitle, 0, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(countriesLabel, 1, 0);
            });

            listdata.ItemTemplate = cell;
        }
```

Comment: Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: hmm i will try, wait

Comment: in Edit i added a quick example, i think its running.. wasn't able to test. hope its not confusing.. thanks anyway